# it os poosible to do Performance Tetsing on Mendix APP Website

Tags: performance, jmeter, mendix

***Is it possible to record JMeter scripts for performance testing Mendix App?***

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, take a look at [Load Testing Your Mendix Applications](https://ww2.mendix.com/cw-load-testing-your-apps) webinar

1. Record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)
2. Perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters
3. Perform parameterization of the test (i.e. credentials for different users and other test data)
4. Ensure that your test is doing what it's supposed to be doing by running it with 1-2 users/iterations and inspecting requests and responses using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
5. [Add more users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) and run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
6. Analyze the results using HTML Reporting Dashboard

More information: [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)